# Conversion of C# to VB.net List<T> has error

Tags: c#, vb.net, object-initializers

I'm trying to convert some C# code to VB but I’m getting an error. What would be the correct VB syntax?

C#

```
return new List<string>   {"First Name", "Last Name", "First & Last Name", "None"};
```

VB

```
Return New List(Of String)() From {"First Name", "Last Name", "First & Last Name", "None"}
```

And how about would I convert this too?
Dim list As New List(Of Country)() From { New Country() With { Key .Name = "Select Country", Key .Code = "0" } }

Thanks

Comment: That compiles if you put it in a "Function ...() As List(Of String)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collection initialization is supported in VB10 (part of Visual Studio 2010), but not in VB9 (VS 2008). The syntax you posted is correct for VB10.

```
Dim foos As New List(Of String)() From {"Foo", "Bar"}
```

In VB9, you would just need to handle it the old fashioned way

```
Dim foos as New List(of String)()
foos.Add("Foo")
foos.Add("Bar")
```

VB9 does support array initialization

```
Dim foos As String() = New String() {"Foo", "Bar"}
```

However, the array is not as functional as the `List(of T)`, but if you do not need to add or remove elements, you can certainly use an array instead of the list.

Comment: To have a one-liner in vb9, you could write : 
Return (New String() {"First Name", "Last Name", "First & Last Name", "None"}).ToList()

Comment: How about this case??? Dim list As New List(Of Country)() From { New Country() With { Key .Name = "Select Country", Key .Code = "0" } }